# Using regex to match everything before the word containing a comma

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have this sentence:

> Four score and seven years ago, our forefathers

I want to obtain the string up to the word ending with the comma (i.e the the word **ago**) but not word with the comma itself.

In the above example I would like to match the bolded text:

**Four score and seven years** ago, our forefathers

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP asked for everything *up to* the word with the comma.  That can be done like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $s = 'Four score and seven years ago, our forefathers';
print "$1\n" if ($s =~ /^([^,]+)\b\w+,.*/);
```

Result is

```
Four score and seven years
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see why you can't just use $1 inside the `if`, could you please help explain why you substitute with the pattern to be matched again?  couldn't you do `my $t = $1` as the body of the if?  Well, that and the `print`

Comment: I've seen that a few times, but am used to using this as a substitution.  Will use your suggestion.

Comment: That assumes your words contain only “word” characters. It doesn't allow for punctuation of any sort

Comment: OP did say "word", so the regex uses word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(.*?) \w+,           <-- you can use \s instead of a space: (.*?)\s\w+,
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/xS9rF9/1)**

Below, you can see in green your captured content
[image]

This regex will do:

```
(.*?) \w+,
  ^   ^
  |   +-- the first word with a spaces before and a comma
  +--- captures everything (ungreedy) until the first word which contains a comma
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter but I think you could explain the regex may be.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan Thanks for constructive comment, I have improved the answer with that

Answer (score 1):

This solution matches all characters from the start of the string until it reaches a point that is followed by optional spaces, then optional non-spaces, then a comma. Note that it will also stop before words that *contain* a comma, like `abc,def` but I assume that's okay?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = 'Four score and seven years ago, our forefathers';

print "$1\n" if $s =~ /((?:(?!\s*\S*,).)*)/;
```

**output**

```
Four score and seven years
```